# Set orientation horizontal to items inside menu in a NavigationView

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I have a NavigationView that has an `app:headerLayout` and an `app:menu` that has three groups of items. One of this groups is made for social media:

```
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_facebook"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_facebook"
            android:title="@string/nav_drawer_facebook" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_twitter"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter"
            android:title="@string/nav_drawer_twitter" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_instagram"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_instagram"
            android:title="@string/nav_drawer_instagram" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_google_plus"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_google"
            android:title="@string/nav_drawer_googleplus" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="@string/nav_drawer_share" />
    </menu>
```

So my question is if there is any way to make the orientation of this menu horizontal:

At this moment it looks like this:

[image]

But I would like it to look like this:

[image]

I would like to show the icons next to the other to safe some space. I know I could achieve this doing a custom layout but I would like to know if there is a way to do this with the `app:menu`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanxs in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/action_layout"
```

into an item,
where  `action_layout` is the layout that you want to show in horizontal orientation here is an example:

```
<item
   android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
   android:title="layout"
   app:actionLayout="@layout/action_layout" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this line

**app:showAsAction="always"**

Answer (score 0):

I do this but everytime I am making mistake I am writing this...

```
<item
android:id="@+id/nav_item"
android:title="@string/title"
android:actionlayout="@layout/mylayout_nav_item" />
```

But Instead Write This...

```
<item
android:id="@+id/nav_item"
android:title="@string/title"
app:actionlayout="@layout/mylayout_nav_item" />
```

It is not showing

- app:actionLayout

but you have to type it...
It will not show error when you give layout and all